# The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception in WCF RIA Services

Tags: c#, wcf-ria-services, entity-framework-6

I have recently updated EntityFramework in my Wcf Application from v5 to v6.  After publishing  the service , service works fine for few hours. Later all services throws an exception like below, I tried all the solutions that are suggested , please Can any one  help me,

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><s:Fault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">
a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.</faultstring><detail>
<ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException>
<HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException><HelpLink i:nil="true"/><InnerException i:nil="true"/><Message>Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b77a5d561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)</Message>
<StackTrace>   at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError)&#xD;
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.Init(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)&#xD;
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.RuntimeConfigurationFactory.InitWithRestrictedPermissions(RuntimeConfigurationRecord configRecord, FactoryRecord factoryRecord)&#xD;
   at System.Configuration.RuntimeConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord)&#xD;
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean&amp; isRootDeclaredHere)</StackTrace><Type>System.IO.FileLoadException</Type></InnerException>
<Message>An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for entityFramework: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5d561934e089' or one of its dependencies.
 The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\apps.sysinformation.net\HelpDesk\web.config line 5)</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Configuration.
BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean&amp; isRootDeclaredHere)&#xD;
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object&amp; result, Object&amp; resultRuntimeObject)&#xD;
   at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)&#xD;
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..ctor()&#xD;
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig..cctor()</StackTrace><Type>System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException</Type></InnerException><Message>The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.</Message>
<StackTrace>   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)&#xD;
   at service1..ctor(Boolean proxyCreationEnabled)&#xD;
   at service1.ValidateUserIT()&#xD;
   at service1.GetTickets_ForDashBoard()&#xD;
   at SyncInvokeGetTickets_ForDashBoard(Object , Object[] , Object[] )&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)&#xD;
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><Type>System.TypeInitializationException</Type></ExceptionDetail></detail></s:Fault></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you publish version 6.0 of the Entity Framework DLLs? Look at your inner exception: "Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=b77a5d561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference."

Comment: Yes I have checked Entity Framework dlls, version is 6.0.0.0 only.

Comment: Just for clarification, suppose if some dlls are missing or if it is pointing to previous version, then service should not work at all. But in my case service is working fine for few hours. How it is possible.

Comment: And one more thing is when services stops, if we copy and replace the same web config file again, the services works fine but only for few hours.